# Paramiko: ssh.exec_command to collect output says open channel in response

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, remote-server, paramiko

I have python script with paramiko and ssh somewhat as below

```
import paramiko

# setup ssh connection this works. no problem.
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn = ssh.connect(MACHINEIP, username=ROOTUSER, password=ROOTUSER_PASSWORD, port=22)

# This first ssh exec works perfect. 
(sshin1, sshout1, ssherr1) = ssh.exec_command(cmd1)

# When I print the output of 2nd and 3rd ssh exec, I get output saying of channel open
(sshin2, sshout2, ssherr2) = ssh.exec_command(cmd2)
print sshout2
(sshin3, sshout3, ssherr3) = ssh.exec_command(cmd3)
print sshout3
```

Channel open messages in output when exec_command is used more than once to collect output:

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 2 (open) window=2097152 
   -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x1d42bd0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) 
(active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 6 (open) window=2097152 
   -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x1d42bd0L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) 
(active; 2 open channel(s))>>>
```

**How can I close this open channel?** Or any solution on this? I am using python 2.7.

Comment: first cmd1 not ended before cmd2 tries to start?

Comment: @eri Its just a normal command. Like `ls`, so shouldnt be the case

Comment: @eri I did felt that first ssh.exec didnt finish or close as per the message but have no idea how to close them.

Comment: try read sshout1 until EOF

Comment: @eri its solved found solution which i put below as answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should have used as `sshout.read()` and rather I used `sshout` only while printing.