# Combining interactive shell and recv_exit_status method using Paramiko

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko, interactive

I am using paramiko for SSH with my remote devices.
and I am make communication with them using paramiko shell (`invoke_shell()` method) for interactivity.
The main problem with paramiko shell (as I've read in many answers here) is that there is no guarantee that paramiko SSHClient methods which indicates that the server finished writing such as `recv_exit_status()` and `exit_status_ready()` will behave as expected.

So I created mechanism that will read the last line of the output from the shell and determine if this line contains only shell's prompt in such case the command execution was finished.
This is works in case there is **no changes in prompt**.

Now I've read here [Wait until task is completed on Remote Machine through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485647/wait-until-task-is-completed-on-remote-machine-through-python) that 'exec_command()' method return tuple 'stdin, stdout, stderr' and preforming `stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()` will block channel until it is done.

My question is if I will create such a tuple and will preform `stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()` with `stdout` that I will get when I am open on each interactive command (meaning I will do 'shell_chan.send('something')' and then will do `stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()`) will it do the job? will it return only when interactive command has finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SSHClient.recv_exit_status` signals that the *channel* has closed.

The "shell" channel closes only when the shell closes. A "shell" is a black box with input and output. Nothing else. There's no way SSH, let alone Paramiko, will be able to tell anyhow, when individual commands in the shell have finished. The `shell_chan.send('something')` is not a signal to SSH to *execute a command*. It simply sends an arbitrary input to the "shell". Nothing else. It's totally at the shell disposition how the input is interpreted. All that the SSH/Paramiko gets back is an arbitrary unstructured output. Paramiko cannot interpret it anyhow for you.

---

If you need to be able to tell when a command has finished, you need to use "exec" channel ([`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) method in Paramiko). You should not use the "shell" channel, unless you are implementing an interactive SSH terminal client, like PuTTY (or in rare cases, when you talk to an limited SSH server that does not implement the "exec" channel, as it often the case with dedicated devices, such as routers, switches, etc).

---

For related questions, see:

- [Execute multiple dependent commands individually with Paramiko and find out when each command finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50962485/850848)
- [How to get each dependent command execution output using Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58179070/850848)
- [Use the same SSH object to issue "exec_command()" multiple times in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30611230/850848)
- [Execute (sub)commands in secondary shell/command on SSH server in Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50708225/850848)
- [Invoke multiple commands inside a process in interactive ssh mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55469294/850848)
- [Executing command using Paramiko exec_command on device is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30603219/850848)
- [What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)