# Interative shell paramiko how to read input like the exec_command

Tags: python, paramiko

When using paramiko exec_command without the interactive shell, it's really easy to get the output.

However I need to use the interactive shell and it seems a pain to read the output of a single command. I couldn't find a demo or any example of this.

I tried using something like : [Implement an interactive shell over ssh in Python using Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821184/implement-an-interactive-shell-over-ssh-in-python-using-paramiko?lq=1)

But it's in really bad shape.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `paramiko` for it.

Just use `paramiko` to open passwordless ssh connection and then implement your method, using `subporcess` module.

For example:

```
def run_shell_remote_command(remote_host, remote_cmd):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-nx', remote_host, remote_cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError("%r failed, status code %s stdout %r stderr %r" % (
                remote_cmd, p.returncode, stdout, stderr))
        return stdout.strip()  # This is the stdout from the shell command
```

Comment: The problem with that is I have to run a lot of command in sequence, and it's too slow/useless to open a process for every command.

Comment: Then I guess some RPC library may suite your needs. I'd used python's `RPyc`. If you interested I'll post usage example here.

Comment: What do you think of using netcat on remote and communicating with it?

Answer (score 0):

After using the solution given in the link, what do you mean by "it's in really bad shape"?

The output had some unnecessary characters so I removed them, please see the **edited** solution.

Comment: I think it should be in a class to be easily reusable anywhere.

Comment: I agree, but it can be very easily done in a few minutes. If you have problems with making it a class please say so and I'll edit the code.

Comment: I updated the code according to your request. Now it's a completely reusable class.

Comment: yes better but I don't see the _print_exec_out being really useful at all. Probably better to use a Logger.

Comment: You were right, no need for _print_exec_out in the solution. I updated the code. thanks