# Unable to get login prompt via ssh using python script

Tags: python-2.7

```
enter code here

#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
import sys
import time
import Tkinter
import time, os, threading
from Tkinter import *
a=Tkinter.Tk()



#A function that logins and execute commands
def fn():
    HOST=raw_input('Enter HOST IP: ')

    USER=raw_input('Enter USER NAME: ')

    PASS=raw_input('Enter PASSWORD: ')

    client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
    client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
    print "SSH connection to %s established" %HOST
    com="cat /etc/motd"
    print "Welcome to Account",
    com1=raw_input("Enter the command:")
    com2=raw_input("Enter if you you want to run multiple command:")
    #Gather commands and read the output from stdout
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command(com)
    print stdout.read()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command( com1)
    print stdout.read()
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command( com2 )
    print stdout.read()
    client1.close()
    top = os.system("sudo su -")
    s = str(top)
    print "Logged out of device %s" %HOST



b = Button(a, text='Welcome to the Login World', command=fn)
b.pack()
b.mainloop()
```

Output are below::

```
[root@xyz ~]#
Enter HOST IP: 10.12.132.143
Enter USER NAME: abc
Enter PASSWORD:*************
SSH connection to 10.129.136.150 established
Welcome to  Account Enter the command:uptime;uname -a
Enter if you you want to run multiple command:

01:02:48 up 4 days, 15:28,  3 users,  load average: 1.02, 1.01, 1.00
Linux   10.12.132.143 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 10:22:33 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@xyz ~]#   -->this is the error it should login to  10.12.132.143 server but it is login to my master server
[root@xyz ~]#.
```

Comment: *this is the error it should login to  10.12.132.143 server but it is login to my master server*

Nope, as you can see from the `uname -a` output, the commands get executed on the remote server.  If you're expecting to have an interactive prompt on the remote server, this is not how you do it with paramiko.  But it's not really clear what your question is.

Comment: Thanks Levit for the quick response..As you mentioned the command uname -a get executed on the remote server..yes it is correct but what i want once command get executed after that it should go to remote server login prompt.That particular thing i m unable to do.I think i have done mistake here below. top = os.system("sudo su -")
    s = str(top)
    print "Logged out of device %s" %HOST    -->because of sudo su it logged in to master server.Please help me with the code i wanted to stay login in the remote server itself.Thanks in advance

Comment: You might be looking for [Implement an interactive shell over ssh in Python using Paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35821184/1072229)

Comment: What i mean once command get executed it should stay logged in(Need  login prompt)to the same remote server.But it is logged out and went to the master server.Python version which i m using 2.7.9

Comment: Hi Grisha,i have check the http://stackoverflow.com/q/35821184/1072229,but unable to connect to remote server after ran the command .Please provide if any concerns